# Which order? ProGuard + JWrapper + Launch4J

Tags: java, javafx, proguard, launch4j, jwrapper

I understand that StackOverflow is geared towards answering specific questions and avoiding subjective opinion. I feel that my question(s) have only one correct answer and therefore I’m posting here.

I’ve created a Java desktop app (JavaFX) which I plan to distribute for commercial use. I’ve read that Java code is easily reverse-engineered so it’s critical to obfuscate using something like ProGuard. I’d like to package my app so that users double click a .exe (which they download from my site) and then an installer is run like any standard software does. This appears to be outside the scope of ProGuard, but I’ve found JWrapper and Launch4J which both seem to provide similar functionality. Both claim to wrap jars into Windows native executables, show splash screens, include JRE, but I'm confused where they differ.

Specifically, I need the following:

- Installation Wizard (namely to place the exe somewhere safe + make shortcut on desktop, and also add the EULA somewhere).
- Add EULA (End-User License Agreement) which specifies user’s limitations
- Web updates for the app (JWrapper seems to provide this using URL + build path)
- Ability to protect the app (somewhat) using licensing (License3j seems promising).

Their features can be found [here](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://www.jwrapper.com/compare.html) but only JWrapper mentions the ability to [perform web updates](http://www.jwrapper.com/getting-started.html) and mentions desktop shortcuts (which I assume can also write a EULA.txt somewhere).

So, after I have finished writing code, in which order should ProGuard, JWrapper and Launch4j be applied? I’m guessing ProGuard first (to shrink, optimize and obfuscate) and then JWrapper and then Launch4j? Or only 2 of 3?

Feel free to also suggest additional methods, tools, or concepts which I may be missing. Thank you!

Comment: JWrapper people also offer JWCrypt which they claim is highly effective code protection, but it is not free.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks. It looks like $500/year  though so a free alternative is always preferred. That isn't realistic though, so I wonder, if I put all my sensitive-data handling on the server side, and pay for a reputable company to provide their protection services, isn't that better than JWCrypt? My app would only contain mostly skeleton code and would request the "guts" of the code from the server throughout its running process. Any thoughts? TY.

Comment: If you can keep the code you want to protect on the server side then obviously that is well protected assuming the server is not compromised. 

But your last statement suggest pulling the code from the server to the client side and that is of course no more secure from reverse engineering than having it on the client app in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems out of scope for Stackoverflow, but to answer it:

1. apply ProGuard first on your application, keeping the main method of your application
2. apply either launch4j or jwrapper (up to you to choose) on the jar processed by ProGuard

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.